# xmllint で、タグの中身だけを取得したい

Tags: shellscript, unix

rest api をたたいた結果を、 xmllint で処理することがあります。このとき、自分の知識では、以下のようにほしいタグを抽出することはできても、その中身だけを取り出すことができないと思っています。

もちろん、結果をさらに sed で処理するなどすれば、タグの中身を抽出するのはできるのですが、ちょっとしたスクリプトを書くときなどに、いちいちこれを記述するのは手間です。xmllint だけで、タグの中身だけを出力することはできませんでしょうか。

---

例えばのコマンド

```
curl http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues.xml |
    xmllint --xpath /issues/issue/id -
```

今現在の出力:

```
<id>23505</id><id>23502</id><id>23501</id><id>23498</id><id>23497</id><id>23495</id><id>23493</id><id>23491</id><id>23488</id><id>23478</id><id>23472</id><id>23471</id><id>23470</id><id>23467</id><id>23463</id><id>23459</id><id>23458</id><id>23448</id><id>23444</id><id>23434</id><id>23430</id><id>23429</id><id>23425</id><id>23423</id><id>23419</id>
```

ほしい出力:

```
23505
23502
23501
23498
23497
23495
23493
23491
23488
23478
23472
23471
23470
23467
23463
23459
23458
23448
23444
23434
23430
23429
23425
23423
23419
```

Comment: `--xpath '/issues/issue/id/text()'` でいいんじゃないか、と思ったのですが、完全に密着して出てきてしまいますね。

Comment: XPath 2.0 なら、`string-join(/issues/issue/id/text(), " ")` かなあ… (htmllintは対応していないけど)

Comment: ちょっとゴミが混じりますが、一度ファイルに落として、 echo 'cat /issues/issue/id/text()' | xmllint --shell issues.xml` を加工すればなんとかなるかな。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回りくどい方法になりますが、以下の様にすると期待通りの出力結果にはなります(非効率ではありますが)。

```bash
$ curl -sO http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues.xml
$ cnt=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(/issues/issue/id)' issues.xml)
$ for((i=1;i<=$cnt;i++)){
    xmllint --xpath "/issues/issue[$i]/id/text()" issues.xml
    echo
  }
```

xmllint にこだわりがなければ python などを使う方が良いかと思います。

```python
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for id in ET.parse(sys.stdin).getroot().findall('issue/id'):
  print id.text
```